# Find all registered mime-types / url scheme protocols (intent filters) on iOS ( iPhone / iPad / iPod )

Tags: iphone, ios, mobile-safari, mime-types, url-scheme

I'm a mobile web developer, and I'd like to test a few iOS devices to see what mime-types and url schemes the average iOS device can accept.

On Android I'm able to install an app called PackageExplorer that lists all the "intent filters" for all the apks and lists what file mime-types (image/png, text/html, text/x-vcard) and url schemes (like geo:, tel:, sms:, mailto:, http://youtube.com) the app handles.

It would be really nice if I could tell what schemes and mime-types are supported/registered from the server or browser side on my mobile webpages, but if that's not possible, I'm looking for a display or an app in iOS to view all the registered file mime-types and url scheme protocols that the device currently supports with all it's installed apps.

How do i find all the registered scheme/mime intent filters on an iOS device?

UPDATE: I don't know if it's complete, but I found an official list of url schemes sported in mobile safari: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html (still looking for mime-types etc.)

Comment: As far as I'm aware, this isn't possible — all you can do is take your list of URL schemes and ask the device whether it supports each in turn, via UIDevice. I'm not confident enough to post it as an actual answer though.

Comment: ya, I did see that it was possible to ask the device like that in a 'native' app if it supports a url, but I'm still hoping there is some way to find all supported mime-types and schemes... I only develop mobile web apps, and being able to get a good idea on what file types and protocols are supported and I can use in links and downloads would be incredibly useful to know.

Answer (score 1):

This information is not available per se. You can however build an app that tries out content of varying types with different content-types and look whether this displays nicely or doesn't.

We've had one situation where the content type for Powerpoint was not registered on the web server and thus UIWebView was unable to display it. It will in these cases respond with a specific error code instead of didFinishLoading. When it was fixed on the server it started working in the app as well.

A slight complication there is that the test files would have to served by a web server because fileURL-based documents don't have a content type. There webkit inside UIWebView auto-detects the file type.

Though in all likelihood this information will prove to be useless to you for a simple reason: apps can always register to open certain file types on the device. The document interaction controller can be used to hand off the opening of the content in this other app. And since this extends the number of viewable document types infinitely you can never how to have a complete list.

So what you really would want is a list of these types of files that UIWebView can display, but you have this list already, you have quoted Apple's URL in your question.